# SharePoint 2010 Connectable webparts

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I wanted to create a custom webpart with acts as both consumer and provider.

So I want my custom webpart to act as a bridge between two OOB sharepoint webparts.

WP1 -> WP2 -> WP3

I want to get the data from WP1 and wanted it to manupulate it and then send it to WP3 for filtering.

My issues are :

1.I want the provider to provide data to WP3 only after WP1 send the data to consumer. Is that possible ?

2.How can I send the data (received from WP1) from consumer class to provider class ?

Can anybody help ? or can suggest some alternative solution ?